# How to get the fields from intricacy file

Tags: linux, parsing, awk

The text file:

```
$ cat filename.txt 
2017-07-15 00:00:27,000 NAME: THT TYPE: S {"cp":"R3"} 
2017-07-15 00:00:27,301 NAME: THT TYPE: S {"cp":"R3"} 
2017-07-15 00:00:26,993 NAME: THT TYPE: M {"bl":"t","cp":"R1","scp":"T5"}.
```

The command line that I tried:

```
$ cat filename.txt |awk '{print $1,$2,$4,$6,$7}'
2017-07-15 00:00:27,000 THT S {"cp":"R3"}
2017-07-15 00:00:27,301 THT S {"cp":"R3"}
2017-07-15 00:00:26,993 THT M {"bl":"t","cp":"R1","scp":"T5"}
```

The desired output:

```
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3 
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3 
017-07-15 00,THT,M,R1
```

I think we can use "IF" but i have not any idea to use "IF" with AWK.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Input_file is same as sample shown here. If yes then try following awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F'[ :{"]' 'NF>18{print substr($1,2),$2 s1 $7 s1 $10 s1 $21;next} {print substr($1,2),$2 s1 $7 s1 $10 s1 $16}' s1=","   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk -F'[ :{"]' 'NF>18{
                    print substr($1,2),$2 s1 $7 s1 $10 s1 $21;
                    next
                 }
                 {
                    print substr($1,2),$2 s1 $7 s1 $10 s1 $16
                 }
           ' s1=","  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{match($NF,/"cp":"[^"]+/); print substr($0,2,12), $4, $6, substr($NF,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}' file
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3
017-07-15 00,THT,M,R1
```

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk '{ $7=gensub(/.*"cp":"([^"]+)".*/,"\\1","g",$7); 
       print substr($1,2)" "substr($2,1,2),$4,$6,$7  }' OFS=',' filename.txt
```

The output:

```
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3
017-07-15 00,THT,S,R3
017-07-15 00,THT,M,R1
```

---

- `$7=gensub(/.*"cp":"([^"]+)".*/,"\\1","g",$7)` - capturing `"cp"` attribute value